# start/stop javascript function on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, timing, jquery-timing

I have a javascript function I using jquery and [jquery-timing](https://github.com/creativecouple/jquery-timing) that loops through an ul of images and text changing opacity.

```
function gridautomate() {

griditem.repeat().each($).find("img").animate({"opacity" : "1"},500, $).wait(7000).wait(noHover).animate({"opacity" : ".5"}, 500, $);
griditem.repeat().each($).find(".quote").animate({"opacity" : "1"},500, $).wait(7000).wait(noHover).animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 500, $);
```

};

I have another function that changes does the same but on hover.

```
function gridanimate() {

griditem.hover(

    function(){
    $(this).find("img").animate({"opacity" : "1"},0);
    $(this).find(".quote").animate({"opacity" : "1"},0);
    },

    function(){
    $(this).find("img").animate({"opacity" : ".5"},0);
    $(this).find(".quote").animate({"opacity" : "0"},0);
    gridautomate();
    }

);
```

}

What I would like to do is toggle starting the 1st function on hover i.e. stop on hover in and start on hover out.  Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

i am not understanding the question. though you can look into the stop() method [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('#hoverme-stop-2').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('img').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('img').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: You can see an example here [link](http://thesrpr.com/jvs) I want the animation loop to stop when one hovers over an image.  I tried stop.  No dice